# Unable to expose existing control on a new project form

Tags: templates, tfs

TFS 2017 on-premise Version 15.117.27024.0

I have a custom Work Item field which exists as a global field, and has been added to work item templates in other projects on the same instance without issue. I've added the custom field to the User Story template for a new TFS Project (which uses the same TFS project template as other projects), and added it to the layout under the 'Value Area' control. Whatever I try, I cannot get the field to show in the web UI of TFS, but when I preview form using the Visual Studio Process Editor add-in, the field shows.

I've tried moving the control into another group, a different column, re-ordering the controls in the column, cleared cache, tried incognito, tried another users machine who has access to the same project. When the other user edits the template, he can see my new field in the template editor.

Exported the XML for the WIT using witadmin, and the elements are there as expected as a Field and as a control in the correct group & column.

Comment: Which TFS version do you use? did you try export the XML and check there?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: The field exist in the `<WebLayout>`?

Comment: Ah ha! No, it's not in the <weblayout>. I'll add it in and re-upload the XML and report back.

Comment: That got it, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I add it also as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS 2017 and higher versions the fields should be exist also in the `<WebLayout>` to be displaying in the TFS web interface.

In your case the field exist only in the `<Layout>` so you can see him only in Visual Studio.