# Work Items not changes after update *.wit

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm using TFS 15.117.27414.0 (Tfs2017.Update3) on premise and trying to update some fields (labels for example) on an existing work item type using Visual Studio 2017 and Power Tools.
Since some days ago all works fine but now when saving my WIT and open it again I can find my changes but when using this work item on TFS website i see old values.

On screenshot you can see the evidence that i saved my wit and the website does not contains my changes.

I tried to restart my client and clear cache, tried to use other browsers on different device but nothing changes.

Old values
[image: old values]

New values
[image: new values]

Missing values
[image: old values]

Comment: The power tools edit the old form layout. The work item is showing the new weblayout that is not configured via the power tools. Are you updating both locations?

Comment: Hi Niel, how can I update the "weblayout location"?

Comment: This is the same as my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900914/unable-to-expose-existing-control-on-a-new-project-form?noredirect=1#comment98462734_55900914, and the answer within will work for you too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to expose existing control on a new project form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900914/unable-to-expose-existing-control-on-a-new-project-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the WebLayout element to define the layout and controls that appear on work item forms displayed through the web portal. It supports the new work item experience. It is in addition to the Layout element which defines the form elements that appear when viewed through Visual Studio and other non-web clients.

You need to export WIT definition by using the command below first:

`witadmin exportwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:ProjectName /n:TypeName /f:"DirectoryPath/FileName.xml"`

More details please refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=azure-devops#import-and-export-wit-definition-files-on-premises-xml

Then customize the work item type under **WebLayout** section, check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops

Comment: I'll try your way. I suppose that after I finished to customize my Work Item I have to "push it" again on TFS, right?

`witadmin importwitd /collection:CollectionURL /f:"DirectoryPath/FileName.xml" /p:ProjectName`

Comment: Yes, you need to import the WIT definition after customization.

Comment: It works, great! I had to export my WIT with "witadmin export" command, delete manually "weblayout" node on the XML, open the WIT with Visual Studio Power Tools ("Edit WIT from local"), do my stuff, save it and import again on TFS using "witadmin import" command.